# Design Preamble Mac OS X Mas

Tags: macos, app-store, electron, single-page-application, appstore-approval

I recently packaged my app for MAC Store and was rejected. Below is the message sent to me by review team. When i testing using development mode everything works fine but I can't picture where i am getting something wrong. Any idea would be appreciated. **App was built using Electron.**

> **Design Preamble**
>
> The user interface of your app is not consistent with the macOS Human
>   Interface Guidelines.
>
> Specifically, we found that when the user closes the main application
>   window there is no menu item to re-open it.
>
> **Next Steps**
>
> It would be appropriate for the app to implement a Window menu that
>   lists the main window so it can be reopened, or provide similar
>   functionality in another menu item. macOS Human Interface Guidelines
>   state that "The menu bar [a]lways contains [a] Window menu".
>
> Alternatively, if the application is a single-window app, it might be
>   appropriate to save data and quit the app when the main window is
>   closed.
>
> For information on managing windows in macOS, please review the
>   following sections in Apple Human Interface Guidelines:
>
> The Menu Bar and Its Menus
>   The Window Menu
>   The File Menu
>   Clicking in the Dock
>   Window Behavior
>   Please evaluate how you can
>   implement the appropriate changes, and resubmit your app for review.

Comment: I solved it by calling app.quit() on x button clicked. Apple doesn't want us to keep app on the dock when x button clicked.

Answer (score 5):

The Problem is that after the Application is minimized by pressing the `x button`,  there is no way for the user to open it again from the dock.

One way to fix this is to just `terminate` the Application when the `x button` is clicked.

I had the same issue and fixed it by adding this function in `AppDelegate`. This solution is for `Swift 4.2`

```
func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Now the Application terminates, when the `x button` is clicked.

Comment: How could you just relaunch the ViewController when pressing on a window menu item? Would be more consistent with the general behaviour of apps on MacOSX

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Xamarin, edit your AppDelegate.cs to create a menu to reopen the main window:

```
    public class AppDelegate : FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        NSWindow window;

        public override NSWindow MainWindow
        {
            get
            {
                return window;
            }
        }

        public AppDelegate()
        {
            var style = NSWindowStyle.Closable | NSWindowStyle.Resizable | NSWindowStyle.Titled;
            var rect = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(100, 100, 1024, 768);

            window = new NSWindow(rect, style, NSBackingStore.Buffered, false);
            window.TitleVisibility = NSWindowTitleVisibility.Hidden;
        }

        private NSMenu MakeMainMenu()
        {
            // top bar app menu
            NSMenu menubar = new NSMenu();
            NSMenuItem appMenuItem = new NSMenuItem();
            menubar.AddItem(appMenuItem);

            NSMenu appMenu = new NSMenu();
            appMenuItem.Submenu = appMenu;

            // add separator
            NSMenuItem separator = NSMenuItem.SeparatorItem;
            appMenu.AddItem(separator);

            // add open menu item
            string openTitle = String.Format("Open {0}", "MyApp");
            var openMenuItem = new NSMenuItem(openTitle, "o", delegate
            {
                // Get new window
                window.MakeKeyAndOrderFront(this);
            });
            appMenu.AddItem(openMenuItem);

            // add quit menu item
            string quitTitle = String.Format("Quit {0}", "MyApp");
            var quitMenuItem = new NSMenuItem(quitTitle, "q", delegate
            {
                NSApplication.SharedApplication.Terminate(menubar);
            });
            appMenu.AddItem(quitMenuItem);
            return menubar;
        }

        public override void DidFinishLaunching(NSNotification notification)
        {
            // finally add menu
            NSApplication.SharedApplication.MainMenu = MakeMainMenu();
            // Insert code here to initialize your application
            Forms.Init();
            //Load Application
            LoadApplication(new App());
            //Did Finish Launching
            base.DidFinishLaunching(notification);
        }

        public override void WillTerminate(NSNotification notification)
        {
            // Insert code here to tear down your application
        }
    }
```

If you are workwing with Cocoa do the same but in the specific language.

Reopen the window with this instruction:

```
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

For electron apps you can add this code to your `index.js` or `main.js` to resolve the issue:

```js
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  app.quit();
});
```